# Hostapd captive portal detection on Android

Tags: raspberry-pi, android, hostapd

I already looked at all related questions, and also at the Chromium project.
I have a working hostapd access point, and a working Captive Portal (works perfectly on ios and mac osx, windows and linux).

BUT - on Android I get no automatic detection, even though I see the request for client3.google.com/generate_204, where I changed the contents of the page and the response code.

Any ideas?

p.s - My software works by doing iptables redirect to port 53 and 80, if the user didn't log in to my captive portal - I respond with "192.168.1.1" for each response - that is my Apache server. 
If I manually go on the android to clients3... I get 302 and redirect to my captive as it should be, but the popup is not triggered. If you go to a place with a captive portal, it does recognize. What can I possibly be missing?

Answer (score 0):

Answer to an old question but anyway..
I think you shouldn't answer to client3.google.com/generate_204 with a 302 code.

Just leave the usual behavior redirecting people to 192.168.1.1 for every request, also for client3.google.com/generate_204

If Android find 302 http response on client3.google.com/generate_204 it supposes you are connected to internet and so, it doesn't show you the captive portal popup.